# Обертка над realloc

Tags: c, инспекция-кода, memory, realloc

Написал свою обертку над `realloc`. Все ли здесь правильно? Может быть есть какие-то недочеты, которых я не заметил?

```
#define qk_realloc(p, n) qk_realloc__(p, &p, n)

/*
=================================
[TEST] The qk_realloc__ function

Функция изменяет размер блока памяти,
на который указывает old. Если операция
выполнена успешно, то old присваивается
адрес нового блока памяти. Если операция
не выполнилась, в куче выделяется НОВЫЙ
блок памяти, в него копируется содержимое
old, старые данные освобождаются и указателю
old присваевает адрес нового блока памяти.
Если память не может быть выделена и для
нового блока, функция возвращает NULL,
при этом входные данные не изменяются.
=================================
*/

void* qk_realloc__(void* old, void* const ptrToOld, const u32 n) {
    void* new = realloc(old, n);

    if (new != NULL) {
        return *((void**) ptrToOld) = new;
    }

    // Тут должно быть сообщение типа: "не удалось выполнить realloc(n)".

    new = qk_malloc(n);

    if (new != NULL) {
        memmove(new, old, n);
        free(old);
        return *((void**) ptrToOld) = new;
    }

    // И тут похожее сообщение...

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Если нужно ускорить резервирование структур, то пулы и фабрики хорошо работают. А realloc может изменить адрес указателя. В программах с интенсивным использованием указателей это очень грустно получается.

Comment: Если `realloc` вернул 0, то не понятно, откуда `qk_malloc` возьмет память.

Comment: @avp, нужно попробовать запросить меньше памяти?

Comment: Вы же запрашиваете те же `n` (или я куда-то не туда смотрю)? Кстати, не помню точно, а проверять лень, но мне кажется, что `*void = ...` не скомпилируется (тут надо к `char **` приводить)

Comment: @avp, Да те же `n`. Теперь думаю запрашивать `n/2` :) На счет `*void = ...` - у меня компилируется, предупреждений нет.

Comment: @avp, да, еще вопросик появился: если система не может выделить память, то все, что мне остается - это сообщить об этом?

Comment: Не думаю, что просто `n / 2` это хорошая идея. Ведь caller-у может требоваться именно `n` и ни байтом меньше (а вы об этом не знаете). В рамках такой идеи можно предложить 2 аргумента для размера -- минимум и желаемая величина. Тогда, если первый realloc вернул 0, можно попробовать другой. (в пределе получится, что вы должны передать в свою функцию целую программу на "предметно-ориентированном языке запросов памяти" -))

Comment: Если памяти нет, то сообщить (или завершить программу с сообщением, как это делает [GNU libiberty xrealloc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libiberty/Functions.html))

Comment: @avp, за время от одной строчки к другой могло произойти переключение контекста на задачу, которая высвободила много памяти.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Логика разработчика этой оболочки совершенно не ясна

1. Зачем в функцию передается одновременно `old` и указатель на `old` (`ptrToOld`)? Если уж вы хотите передавать `ptrToOld`, то по нему можно получить и значение `old`. Зачем передавать `old` отдельно?
2. Почему делается безусловное `memmove(new, old, n);`? А если новый размер больше старого? Также стандартный `realloc` разрешает передавать ему на вход нулевой указатель. Ваш `memmove` не учитывает эту возможность.
3. Почему `ptrToOld` имеет такой странный тип - `void* const`? Почему этот тип не является указателем на указатель?
4. Почему вы решили, что после неудачи `realloc` вы сможете сделать `malloc`? Теоретически, неудачи у `realloc` могут быть разные, но мы-то понимаем, что практически всегда неудача `realloc` - это просто нехватка памяти. Почему вы считаете, что если `realloc` не смог выделить память, то `malloc` сможет?
5. `*((void**) ptrToOld)` - переинтрепретация памяти, возможно нарушение strict-aliasing.
6. Почему `memmove`, а не `memcpy`?

И чего именно вы пытались добиться? Первая мысль была в том, что эта оболочка призвана бороться с недостатками варианта `p = realloc(p, ...)`, но она с ними никак не борется. Так в чем же тогда смысл?

Comment: 1. По моему, где-то читал, что нельзя присвоить указатель на любой объект указателю void** без потери информации.
2. Учту.
3. См. №1
4. Твердо был уверен, что `malloc` сможет :)
5. Можете объяснить поподробнее, что это значит?
6. `memmove` позволяет данным перекрываться.
Если честно, я планировал бороться с этими недостатками, видимо не получилось.

Comment: @Eanmos: Ваше использование `void **` действительно некорректно, но от этой некорректности вы никуда не денетесь.  Она у вас просто перенеслась из типа параметра в точку выполнения каста и присваивания `*((void**) ptrToOld) = new`. По поводу `memmove` - и в каком же сценарии выполнения у вас могут получиться перекрывающиеся данные?

Comment: Как же использовать `void**` корректно? Да, нашел ту книгу Heathefield "C Unleashed": "*В то время как вы можете присвоить указатель на любой объект указателю `void*`, это не обязательно выполняется для указателя `void**`!*". Можете объяснить, что это значит? Может стоит задать отдельный вопрос?

Comment: @eanmos 1. Что `old`, что `ptrToOld` уже потеряли всю информацию о хранимом типе (ибо указатели на `void`). 5. Преобразование не в `char *` и не в `void *` приводит к тому, что компилятор перестаёт считать исходный и преобразованный указатели тождественными (стандарт прямо это разрешает, прописывая для этого случая неопределённое поведение) и иногда ломает программу, генерируя некорректный код. Используйте вместо каста побайтовый перенос сырого значения указателя через `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

> Все ли здесь правильно?

Всё неправильно. Начиная с того, что нет никакой нужды делать обёртки над хорошо себя зарекомендовавшими стандартными функциями.

Я даже не буду смотреть в ваш код, ответьте на простой вопрос: зачем?

Comment: Ну, в принципе, вот в таком `void *my_realloc(void **ptr, size_t newsize)`, который меняет свой первый аргумент и вызывает `exit((perror("my_realloc"), -1))`, если памяти нет, определенный смысл есть (конечно, не для использования внутри библиотек).

Comment: Очень жаль. Если бы посмотрели, то поняли.

Comment: @avp, вы меня смущаете :)

Comment: @PinkTux, просто мне лень постоянно создавать дополнительный указатель, в него помещать результат `realloc`, проверять его на `NULL`, в случае ошибки писать о нехватке памяти и т.д. :) Тут, наверное, еще я сглупил: у меня в коде, если определен дебаг, то пишется кол-во выделенной памяти, сообщения об ошибках и т.д. Пожалуй, добавлю это в вопрос.

Comment: @Eanmos, вы выделяете память под что-то типа `int`, или под структуры? Если это массив `int`, то не ясно, почему вам заранее не известен его размер. Если это что-то типа HTTP-запроса без заголовка Content-Length, то, может, лучше хранить данные очередью блоков и работать с ними конечным автоматом.